# Building and requiring a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I built a gem called prawn_charts and can successfully require the module that wraps all the classes (the classes are all in different files) and the classes from the root directory of the project with this command in irb:

```
require "./lib/prawn_charts.rb"
```

However, when I create the gem with `$ rake build` and `$ rake install`, cd to my home directory, and require the gem in irb, I can only load the wrapper module and not any of the individual classes:

```
~ $ irb
>> require 'prawn_charts'
=> true
>> PrawnCharts # this works
=> PrawnCharts
>> PrawnCharts::YLabelsDataCollector # don't know why this causes an error
NameError: uninitialized constant PrawnCharts::YLabelsDataCollector
```

Here is what the `lib/prawn_charts.rb` file looks like:

```
require 'prawn'
require_relative "./prawn_charts/version"

module PrawnCharts
end

# this loads PrawnCharts::YLabelsDataCollector
Dir["./lib/data_collectors/**/*.rb"].each {|file| require file } 
Dir["./lib/renderers/**/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

I also have this line in the gemspec file:

```
gem.files = `git ls-files`.split($/)
```

EDIT:

This is what I should have had in `lib/prawn_charts.rb`:

```
lib_path = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
Dir["#{lib_path}/prawn_charts/data_collectors/**/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
Dir["#{lib_path}/prawn_charts/renderers/**/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

Comment: 1.Can you make sure `Dir["./lib/data_collectors/**/*.rb"]` really returns the file you want? 2.where is `YLabelsDataCollector ` defined?

Comment: @MikeLi - I checked and Dir["./lib/data_collectors/**/*.rb"]` returns all the files I want.  `YLabelsDataCollector` is defined here: `/lib/data_collectors/graph/y_labels_data_collector.rb`.  The files are all being loaded properly when I work within the gem.  It is just when I package the gem officially and require it in another directory when I run into problems.  Thanks.

Comment: @MikeLi - actually, you were right, I didn't load the files properly.  My loading solution worked in the project root directory, but not any other directory.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dir globbing is relative to your current working directory -- not the gem directory.  This is why it works when you are in the root of your gem, but not when you run it from your home directory.

Tweak it to spit out what files it's trying to load when you run it once installed and you'll see what I mean.

If you've loaded rubygems as well you shouldn't need to do this as it will add the path to the load path so you can just require "data_collectors/......"